# Counting number of previous rows in dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Here is the dataframe:

```
    entryTime             exitTime
    2017-05-31 22:47:08   2017-05-31 22:50:29   
    2017-05-31 22:47:38   2017-06-01 00:00:44   
    2017-05-31 23:59:50   2017-06-01 00:01:58
    2017-06-01 00:01:40   2017-06-01 00:02:00
    dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I want to create a new column 'Position' that counts the number of previous rows where:

entryTime of current row < exitTime of previous row

```
e.g.
    entryTime             exitTime              Position
    2017-05-31 22:47:08   2017-05-31 23:59:59   0
    2017-05-31 22:47:38   2017-06-01 00:00:44   1
    2017-05-31 23:59:50   2017-06-01 00:01:58   2
    2017-06-01 00:01:40   2017-06-01 00:02:00   1
    dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

By using [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)

```
df['position'] = (df.entryTime < df.exitTime.shift(1)).astype(int)

df
            entryTime            exitTime  position
0 2017-05-31 22:47:08 2017-05-31 22:50:29         0
1 2017-05-31 22:47:38 2017-06-01 00:00:44         1
2 2017-05-31 23:59:50 2017-06-01 00:01:58         1
```

Comment: I want the COUNT of the number of previous rows that satisfy the condition